# Can't pass integer as argument to function in prolog

Tags: prolog, integer, arguments

We are trying to do a school project in which we solve a problem of collecting items in an Amazon Building.

We think we have the code almost set up but aren't able to pass a simple integer to a Clause for it to check, we get Wrong ObjectType all the time.

```
domains
posicionInicial = Symbol
posicionFinal= Symbol
posicion = Symbol
idestanteria = Symbol
nombre = Symbol
distancia = integer
cantidad = integer

/* lineapedido = linea (Symbol, integer) */ 
/* pedido = lineapedido* */

predicates

estanteria (idestanteria,posicion)
valido (nombre,posicion,cantidad)
ubicacion (nombre, idestanteria, cantidad)
conectado (posicionInicial, posicionFinal, distancia)
mueve (posicionInicial,posicionFinal,nombre, cantidad, distancia)
resuelve (nombre,cantidad) 


clauses

estanteria(s1,ps1).
estanteria(s2,ps2).
estanteria(s3,ps3).
estanteria(s4,ps4).
estanteria(s5,ps5).
estanteria(s6,ps6).
estanteria(s7,ps7).
estanteria(s8,ps8).

ubicacion(patatas,s1,200).
ubicacion(melones,s1,100).
ubicacion(boligrafos,s2,500).
ubicacion(boligrafos,s3,400).
ubicacion(melocotones,s4,200).
ubicacion(berzas,s4,100).
ubicacion(papeles,s5,500).
ubicacion(boligrafos,s6,400).
ubicacion(plumas,s7,500).
ubicacion(plumas,s8,400).
ubicacion(colonias,s3,150).
ubicacion(ratones,s4,210).

/* Conexiones IDA */    
conectado (pc1,pc2,10).
conectado (pc2,pc3,10).
conectado (pc3,pc4,10).
conectado (pc4,t,10).
conectado (ps1,pc1,5).
conectado (ps2,pc2,5).
conectado (ps3,pc3,5).
conectado (ps4,pc4,5).
conectado (ps6,pc6,5).
conectado (ps7,pc7,5).
conectado (ps8,pc8,5).

/* Conexiones vuelta */
conectado (pc2,pc1,10).
conectado (pc3,pc2,10).
conectado (pc4,pc3,10).
conectado (t,pc4,10).
conectado (pc1,ps1,5).
conectado (pc2,ps2,5).
conectado (pc3,ps3,5).
conectado (pc4,ps4,5).
conectado (pc6,ps6,5).
conectado (pc7,ps7,5).
conectado (pc8,ps8,5).


/* Mueve S -> PC1 */
mueve (s,pc1,nombre, cantidad, distancia):-
    conectado (posicion,posicion, distancia),
    valido (nombre, pc1, cantidad). 

mueve (pc1,ps1,nombre, cantidad, distancia):-
    conectado (posicion,posicion, distancia),
    valido (nombre, ps1, cantidad). 


valido (nombre, posicion, cantidad):-
    estanteria (idestanteria, posicion),
    ubicacion (nombre, idestanteria, cantidad).



/* Resolucion algoritmo */

resuelve (nombre,cantidad):-
    /* lineapedido = [H|T],*/
    /* H = linea (patatas, 200), */ 
    mueve (posicionInicial, posicionFinal, nombre, cantidad, distancia),
    write ("HOLA").




goal 

resuelve(patatas, 1).
```

When we try to compile that, we get this error:
E;Test_Goal, pos: 1922, 512 Type error: Wrong object type

And it takes us to this line:

valido (nombre, posicion, cantidad):-

Can't seem to find why, when it's only passing an integer as argument.
Thanks in advance, if something else needed just tell me.

Comment: You really should look at the Prolog documentation for basic syntax rules. Otherwise, you're going to waste a lot of time chasing errors like these.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to **answer 1** I can tell that you've almost totally typed `symbol`s instead of `variable`s.

Variable name syntax:

1. The first char is *upper-cased letter* or *underscore* ("_");
2. The rest chars are *alpha-numeric chars* of any case or *underscore*;

Replace `symbols` with `variable`s when it's appropriate.

**edit1:**
Example:

```
 domains 
      any=term,
      list = any*
 predicates 
      member(any, list) 
 clauses 
      member(X, [X | _ ]).
      member(X, [ _ | Y]) :- member(X,Y).
```

`"_"` means anonymuous var. Unlike the regular (named) variables, the anonymuous variables are all distinct: `"_"` isn't the name but it's the indicator - "This is an anon. var. don't care about its name"

**edit2:**

useful link:

**Markus Triska**

https://www.metalevel.at/prolog

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm just not understanding but what do you mean by that? 
If I want to declare a variable used to store like list of products (potatoes, pens, etc) shouldn't it be as easy as declaring:

name = Symbol

Or should I type:

Name = symbol

Thanks.

Comment: @kialios Prolog variables aren't declarable. You should replace `nonvar`-terms with variables when it 's appropriate in `clauses` section, so you should write __name=symbol__.

Answer (score 0):

`valido (nombre, posicion, cantidad)` is not a valid rule head or predicate call.

You cannot put a space between the predicate name and the first parenthesis.

For example, `test (1).` does not compile:

```
ERROR: c:/test.pl:1:5: Syntax error: Operator expected
```

but `test(1).` does.

So remove all those spaces.